# python.h file not found after using command on cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

I tried to include python.h but received fatal error

I downloaded a code which includes python.h, but i received fatal error python.h not found. I followed stackoverflow using the command shown below on cygwin

```
apt-cyg install python-devel
```

However, in \usr\include i only find a folder python2.7 with pyconfig.h file only. Is there a way I can copy python.h file to include?

Comment: As an aside, unless your needs are highly specialized, you want to work with the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3. Python 2 was EOLed in 2020.

Comment: Yes. The command for copying a file is `cp`. Alternatively you could use `ln` to create  a symbolic link. Yet another possibility is to leave the file in place and configure your makefile, so that your C compiler also searches python2.7 for header files. I would do the latter, because this provides maximum flexibility, in case you want to play around with several Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

do not use `apt-cyg` as it is unmaintained and not updated to the latest format of Setup.ini format
Use Cygwin Setup.

You should install `python3-devel` or `python39-devel`

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/python3-devel.html